# Verifying key/value pairs between arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a "master" array, and several arrays I have to verify against the master.

The master array is a list of key/value pairs. The other arrays have to be made of some (or all) of these pairs, *nothing else*.

Here is some example to clarify:

```
$master = [1=>'foo', 2=>'bar', 3=>'baz'];
$good_child = [2=>'bar'];
$wrong_child_1 = [2=>'sparta'];
$wrong_child_2 = [42=>'bar'];
```

Currently I'm doing the verification with this quick piece of code:

```
foreach ($child as $key => $value) {
    if ($master[$key] !== $value) {
        // wrong child
    }
}
```

You already may have noticed it would fail with the `$wrong_child_2` above (undefined index), although it's not a problem in the real application (at least for now).

My question is, would there be a better way to make these verifications? Preferably without loops, rather array functions.

Comment: "a better way" --- so 2 lines of code solution is not good enough?

Comment: But anyway, you could: 1. check the arrays size. 2. use `array_intersect_assoc` to get the identical elements. 3. Check that result on step 2 == array length. But it will be more complicated than what you already have

Comment: Thanks, I had missed `array_intersect_assoc()`. I can do `ksort($master); ksort($child); $child === array_intersect_assoc($master, $child);`. I wish I hadn't to apply the `ksort()`'s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`array_diff_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php).

```
$bad = (bool)count(array_diff_assoc($test_array, $master_array))
```

In other words, `$test_array` does not validate if there are any differences, including the index check.

Comment: This function fits sooo perfectly my need! Just use the construct `empty()` for checking for empty arrays ;)

Comment: Ha ha, just forgot [about expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.empty) with PHP < 5.5