# Check if arrays are the same without any key=>value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, `$a = array("a", "b");` and `$b = array("b", "a");`

I want to check if they are equal, I cannot use key=>value pairs as the PHP function populating a `.csv` into an array does not put it into key=>value pairs. (or at least to my understanding). I made this in a sandbox environment and I would appreciate it if it could stay that way. The code for the `.csv` import works and has been tested.

Did a quick Google Search, only examples for key=>value arrays.

PHP was kind enough to give some documentation on the matter : [PHP Documentation on Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

They did not work, as shown here : [DEMO](http://codepad.org/CggsZdpB)

Any tips will be highly appreciated.

EDIT #1

A Mod marked it as duplicate, I do not think it is a duplicate as the question handled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692628/verifying-key-value-pairs-between-arrays), handles with key/value pairs.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You just want to check if hte values in one array are the same as in the second array?

Comment: check this post in the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#70762)

Comment: Not a moderator, just power user with gold [tag:php] badge. Agree it's not a dupe, @Marc can you please reopen this?

Comment: `$a = array('a', 'b'); $b = array('b', 'a'); echo count(array_diff($a, $b))` spits out zero. which is exactly what the "dupe" does.